# Try to get the snapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" in Powershell but i get an error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

I try to get the snapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" in Powershell but i get an error.

```
Add-PSSnaping : no snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 5
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell/16.0.8414.1200) module which can be installed on a per-user basis. This is the preferred installation over the MSI method.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are running the powershell on a machine where SharePoint is not installed.
You can check by running below command if that snap-in available or not?

```
get-pssnapin –registered
```

Try to run the PowerShell on the server where SharePoint is installed.

If you want to run it from pc then you try this workaround: [How to add Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell to machine without SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49967/how-to-add-add-pssnapin-microsoft-sharepoint-powershell-to-machine-without-share)

If you want to use the SPO management then follow the instruction here: [Getting started with SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: I want to connect to SharePoint-Online with powershell. The command get-pssnapin -registered gives me nothing. So I guess nothing Is registered

Comment: check the updated answer for SPO shell configuration

Comment: And I want to use the Powershell ISE and not the sharepoint online management shell

Comment: You have to import to import the modules inside the ISE. something like Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell -Verbose

Comment: Get the error: Import-Module : The specified module 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

Comment: you need to install the module 1st then import those module inside the ISE.

Comment: http://blog.pcfromdc.com/2013/08/powershell-for-sharepoint-in-o365.html

Comment: Is there perhaps another way to use the module without installing it. I am not aloud to install