# how to upload a file to a document library using OData in PowerShell with curl or Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sharepoint-rest-api, odata, curl

As I cannot use `Pnp.PowerShell` with a SharePoint-2019 on premise, AFAIK, I've been trying workd with OData instead, using curl (or PowerShell `Invoke-RestMethod` or falling back to JavaScript `fetch` if needed). Unfortunately it happens to be much more complicated than I thought.

I ended up building this command:

```
curl -vvv -n -X POST  "https://sharepoint.site/site/aaa/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/site/aaa/library/folder')/Files/add" -T a.xlsx -H "Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata" -H "X-RequestDigest: xxxxxx"
```

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

or

```
curl -vvv -n -X POST  "https://sharepoint.site/site/aaa/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/site/aaa/library/folder')/Files/add(url=a.xlsx,overwrite=true)" -T a.xlsx -H "Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata" -H "X-RequestDigest: xxxxxx"
```

HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN

{"odata.error":{"code":"-2130575252, System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException","message":{"lang":"fr-FR","value":"La validation de la sécurité de cette page a expiré. Cliquez sur Précédente dans votre navigateur web, actualisez la page et retentez l'opération."}}}*
Connection #0 to host sharepoint.site left intact

(translation: The security validation of this page has expired. Click Back in your web browser, refresh the page and try again.)

I found this PowerShell function: [Upload-FileToShp](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NVRAppDevOps/2.0.21/Content/Upload-FileToShp.ps1), but I cannot make it work in my case, so doesn't help for having a correct `curl` or `Invoke-RestMethod`!

What's missing? I think it's an SSO issue?

I will be using `Add-PnPFile`, which works (even along SSO!), but I am afraid of using `SharePointPnPPowerShell2019` as a shacky workaround.

Answer (score 0):

if the script will be running on the same machine as the Sharepoint, you can use PS snapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  
#Function to Upload File
Function Upload-AllFilesFromDir($WebURL, $DocLibName, $FolderPath)
{
    #Get the Web and List to upload the file
    $web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
       
    #Get the Target Document Library to upload
    $List = $Web.GetFolder($DocLibName)
  
    #Get the Files from Local Folder
    $Files = Get-ChildItem $FolderPath #You can filter files by: -filter “*.pdf”
 
    #upload the files
    Foreach ($File in $Files)
    {
        #Get the Contents of the file to FileStream
        $stream = (Get-Item $file.FullName).OpenRead()
     
        # Set Metadata Hashtable For the file - OPTIONAL
        $Metadata = @{"Country" = "United States"; "Domain" = "Sales"}
     
        #upload the file             
        $uploaded = $List.Files.Add($File.Name, $stream, $Metadata, $TRUE)
     
        #dispose FileStream Object
        $stream.Dispose()
    }
}
   
#call the upload function
Upload-AllFilesFromDir "https://SharePoint.crescent.com/sites/sitename/" "Shared Documents" "c:\Documents\"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1361849/auto-upload-file-share-documents-to-sharepoint

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was focused on `OData REST API` (as  `PnP.PowerShell` is not any more supported but for SP Online), but another solution like yours is welcome. Why do you say Ìf the script will be running on the same machine as the SharePoint? SharePoint is on a remote server, and behind a SSO authentication. Does `Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` support SharePoint-2019 officially? Most of the time, only SharePoint Online is still supported, and documentation often confusing (at least for me). Where do I get the snap-in for SharePoint-2019 from ?

Comment: Sharepoint 2019 is supported, we are using it for automatied scripts.
I think it is installed automatically with the sharepoint 2019 instalation.
Maybe it is working from other machines, but we use it on the remote machine where the sharepoint is installed, thats why you do not have to authenticate, it is using your windows credentials.

Comment: To get it work from other machines: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49967/how-to-add-add-pssnapin-microsoft-sharepoint-powershell-to-machine-without-share